# Does email client leave messages on GMail server by default?

Tags: 12.04, email, gmail

If I use POP3 and let email client autoconfig everything are copies of my messages left untouched on server? Where is the setting to change that?

Comment: which mail client are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is determined by your settings within Gmail, not the POP client. See Gmail's documentation about [deleting messages in Gmail after POP downloads](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/13290?hl=en&ref_topic=1668962).

The default setting is to leave copies of messages on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you do an auto config for gmail. Your mail client will have configured it as an IMAP account. This means the messages stay on the server.

If you do a POP3 config, your mail client will take the messages from your server and puts them on your computer. Normally they stay a certain amount of time on the server (for example 7 days) before moving completely to your computer.

Both have their advantages.